# How can I make the mouse cursor hide itself when typing?

Tags: 13.10, cursor

It gets in the way. I'd like to have it disappear when I start typing, then reappear if I move it. I've heard of `unclutter` but it sounds like it hides the cursor after it's been "idle" for a while, which isn't what I want--I only want to hide when I'm typing. How could I do this?

Comment: There's an open bug on this subject. Open for **11 years** now. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/16492

Answer (score 6):

You can use [xbanish](https://github.com/jcs/xbanish), it does the job.
Install it and run it simply like that:

```
xbanish
```

Comment: Please don't post answers that consist only of a link - elaborate on the steps needed, on **how** to accomplish the goal by using the mentioned tool.

Comment: I added the command that is only the name of the application.

Comment: Any solution for those of us on wayland?

Answer (score 3):

[xbanish](https://github.com/jcs/xbanish) does it well, I installed and it's working fine.
you may [clone its repo](https://github.com/jcs/xbanish.git)
cd the repo, run make.

you may find the missing headers in the [Ubuntu package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/), check the option;

> packages that contain files named like this

install the packages accordingly.

run the executable and you're good to go.

you may want to run the executable with

> setsid

care to not kill xbanish while typing, instead terminate the process with

> killall -TERM xbanish

Comment: Thanks, it works for me, on Lubuntu LXDE.  Had to compile to install though.

Answer (score -2):

There is a setting I found in dash home when u search mouse.  Click mouse and touch pad, and the is an option that is: disable touch pad when typing.

Hope this helps

Comment: That only seems to work in gedit, for some reason...

Comment: this is not answer for a question